# How to add a sysdate column to a query containing left outer joins

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join

I need a little help here in adding a column to my query that will be used as a 'date extracted' column.
My originaly query looks like:

```
SELECT 
PR.PARENT_ID,
PR.ID as Record_ID,   
PROJECT.NAME as Project_Name,
PR_STATUS_TYPE.NAME  as RECORD_State, 
PERSON_RELATION.NAME as ORIGINATOR,
PR.DATE_OPENED, 
TW_V_AUDIT.S_VALUE as aud,
PR.NAME TITLE
FROM (PR PR 
LEFT OUTER JOIN PROJECT PROJECT ON PR.PROJECT_ID=PROJECT.ID) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN PERSON_RELATION ON PERSON_RELATION.ID = PR.ORIGINATOR_REL_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PR_STATUS_TYPE PR_STATUS_TYPE ON PR.STATUS_TYPE=PR_STATUS_TYPE.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN TW_V_AUDIT ON TW_V_AUDIT.PR_ID = PR.ID
WHERE  
PROJECT.NAME='Audit' 
GROUP BY
PERSON_RELATION.NAME,
PR.ID, 
PR.PARENT_ID,
PROJECT.NAME,
PR_STATUS_TYPE.NAME,
PR.DATE_OPENED,
TW_V_AUDIT.S_VALUE,
PR.NAME
ORDER BY
RECORD_ID;
```

I am looking to add a column that shows the system date which is the following query:

```
Select TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual
```

How would I do so? And I am using sql developer.
Please let me know if anymore information is needed from my end.
Thank you all again in advance.

Sonny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this part:

```
TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as System_Date
```

to your SELECT list

Answer (score 1):

Just add the date column to your Select Statement:

```
SELECT 
PR.PARENT_ID,
PR.ID as Record_ID,   
PROJECT.NAME as Project_Name,
PR_STATUS_TYPE.NAME  as RECORD_State, 
PERSON_RELATION.NAME as ORIGINATOR,
PR.DATE_OPENED, 
TW_V_AUDIT.S_VALUE as aud,
PR.NAME TITLE,
TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as date
FROM (PR PR 
LEFT OUTER JOIN PROJECT PROJECT ON PR.PROJECT_ID=PROJECT.ID) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN PERSON_RELATION ON PERSON_RELATION.ID = PR.ORIGINATOR_REL_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PR_STATUS_TYPE PR_STATUS_TYPE ON PR.STATUS_TYPE=PR_STATUS_TYPE.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN TW_V_AUDIT ON TW_V_AUDIT.PR_ID = PR.ID
WHERE  
PROJECT.NAME='Audit' 
GROUP BY
PERSON_RELATION.NAME,
PR.ID, 
PR.PARENT_ID,
PROJECT.NAME,
PR_STATUS_TYPE.NAME,
PR.DATE_OPENED,
TW_V_AUDIT.S_VALUE,
PR.NAME
ORDER BY
RECORD_ID;
```